# MySQL Reading from a table while it's being written

Tags: mysql

I have a script which writes to a table each day. It takes 5 hours to write.

During this time, if you try to read from the table, it says you can't because it's LOCKED.

Is there a way around this, so you can still read from the table?

Thanks

Comment: Make a read-only copy of the table while you're writing and then replace it once the writing is complete. This is similar to writing new data to `file.new`, and then `mv file.new file` when done-- it insures that `file` is always readable and consistent

Comment: You may also want to confirm your script has a `BEGIN` and a `COMMIT` which is much faster than running queries individually

Comment: Is this an InnoDB table? Normally writing to a table doesn't lock it against reads. Writers do not block readers and vice versa. If the table uses MyISAM or some other storage engine, it may be locked. Or else is your script expliciting using `LOCK TABLES`?